# How update binding properties in other project viewmodel (UWP)?

Tags: c#, uwp, reactiveui

I have UWP UI project and other .NET Standard project with logic (ViewModels). I binded string from viewmodel to view.

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConsoleData}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="18"/>
```

Console data updating with event, which invoking for other thread.

```
    [Reactive] public string ConsoleData { get; set; } = "";

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        _testLogicController = new TestLogicController();
        _testLogicController.OnMessage += OnMessageUpdate;
    }

    private void OnMessageUpdate(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ConsoleData += (string)sender;
        ConsoleData += "\n";
    }
```

After start, program fall with [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWw7v.png). Because viewmodel exists in other project there is no possibility to call Core.Dispather. Please, tell me, how solve this problem?

Comment: Resolved with Reactive.UI ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with `Reactive.UI ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)`